# How to show the selected option in a dropdown menu, with the mongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

how to get data from the select option dropdown menu in mongodb

I face this error --> ReferenceError: Selection is not defined

here I attached all the code and files
how to solve this error ?? what changes I need in my code

customer.model.js file

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

var employeeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        
    discount: {
        type: Number
    },
    finalTotal: {
        type: Number
    },
    selectt: {
        type: Selection
    }
    
});

mongoose.model('Employee', employeeSchema);
```

.html file

```
<h3><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="/customer"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Create New</a> Employee List</h3>
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>         
            
            <th>discount</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {{#each list}}
        <tr>            
            <td>{{this.discount}}</td>
            <td>{{this.selectt}}</td>
            <td>{{this.finalTotal}}</td>          
                      
        </tr>
        {{/each}}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

```
<form action="/customer" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="_id" value="{{employee._id}}">
   <label for="selectt">Select Customer</label>
              <select name="selectt" id="selectt" type="Selection" value="{{employee.selectt}}" required>
                <option value="" disabled selected>Select Customer</option>
                <option value="1">Mark Benson</option>
                <option value="2">Bob Smith</option>
                <option value="3">John Draper</option>
               
              </select>
```

CustomerContoller.js file

```
function insertRecord(req,res){
    var employee = new Employee();
    
    employee.discount = req.body.discount;
    employee.finalTotal = req.body.finalTotal;
    employee.selectt= req.body.selectt;
    employee.save((err, doc) => {
        if(!err)
            res.redirect('customer/list');
        else{
            console.log('error during record insertion : ' +err);

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: can you add error logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When defining mongoose Schema you need to define the data type with a particular field. In your code
`type: Selection` is not a valid data type. So identify the data type for the corresponding field and put it there. For Example,

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

var employeeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        
    discount: {
        type: Number
    },
    finalTotal: {
        type: Number
    },
    selectt: {
        type: String
    }
    
});

mongoose.model('Employee', employeeSchema);
```